# Does "my mother cars" need an apostrophe and S?

Tags: possessives

The first one sounds wrong to me but I'm not sure.

Which one is correct?

> My mother'**s** car**s**

or

> My mother car**s**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one means "the cars that belong to my mother". The "s" on cars makes it plural, and does not affect possession in any way.

The second use of "cars" reads like a verb, but since "car" isn't used as a verb in English, it's wrong.

If you want to refer to the car that belongs to your mother, you can use

> My mother's car

If you want to refer to things that belong to the car that belongs to your mother, you would use a construction like

> My mother's car's headlights are broken.

If you wanted to refer to things that belong to all of several cars that belong to your mother, you could use something like

> My mother's cars' tires need to be replaced.

Comment: `My mother's cars are too old` What about this one?

Comment: @PrisonPants: That would mean that all of the cars that belong to your mother are too old. It would also imply your mother has at least two cars.

Comment: Actually, "my mother cars" is referring to some cars that are like a mother to you.

Comment: @Hot Licks: That would work too, I suppose.

Comment: On the planet [Cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_%28film%29), individuals may have two parents of the same gender, and either or both may be technically the "mother", depending on where parts were scavenged.  Lightning's mother cars are Chick and Sally.

Comment: You guys are getting ridiculous here. The question clearly indicates that the poster has a limited grasp of English syntax, and you're talking about cars parenting other cars on a fictional planet.

Comment: @StevenLittman But a ton of ELL questions are about peculiar uses of specific constructions in specific works...